# GitHub can't use personal access token

Tags: git, github, token

Hellow.
I have folloving github autorization issue.

After August 13 I have to use personal access token for autorization. It is clear.
I've created this access token as it described in [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
Then I try to use it same way it described:

```
git clone https://github.com/my_username/my_repo_name.git
```

But system doesn't ask me for login and password as it described in docs, just tells me: "Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead."

It means that I have login and password in computer memory.
I tryed to reset login and password (for github) by

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

or

```
git config --global --unset user.password
```

but witout any positive result. When I try ty clone or push any code I just get the same massege: "...Please use a personal access token..."

I'm using windows and cmd for git commands.
I've read other subjects regarding to this issues, and all I realise that after using

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

system should ask for login and password, but it doesn't happend, it just print: "...Please use a personal access token..."

What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

P.S.
If the answer was deskribe I'll be glad to get a link.

Comment: And in docs.github.com they describe "If you are not prompted for your username and password" just for Keychain on Mac, but I need the same instructions for Windows

Comment: Side note: docs.github.com auto-directs you to the docs specific to the host OS for whatever browser you are using to reach docs.github.com. They do, however, allow you to select and view pages for other OSes (which is good, some sites are just *too* clever and don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for **Manage Web Credentials** in windows, delete whatever things related to your git credentials, after that you should see the username and password popup whenever required.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I've spent several hours to fix it, and yes that was so easy - just clear data from Manage Web Credentials in windows and enter my personal access token for GitHub. Now GitHub ask for login and password (personal access token) after "git clone" command.